# Installed trigger app, installed node.js, trigger says it can't run npm on Mac

Tags: macos, node.js, npm, trigger.io

New Mac user account. I install the Trigger.io (TriggerToolkit) app for the Mac. It fires up a tab with the apps. I can run the iOS simulator from it - so it is plausibly working installation. I have installed node.js from the node.js website, using the Mac package.

I have node.js as /usr/local/bin/npm (version 1.1.43).

It is found when I type "npm" at a command line.

The path "/usr/local/bin" is on my $PATH.

"/usr/local/bin" is set in my /etc/paths file, system wide.

So the npm executable should be findable by any user, at any time (before or after login, running a terminal, etc).

When I use the web page for the web run, it's OK, until it tries to run npm.

```
[DEBUG] running run_web((), {})

[DEBUG] Running: npm install

[DEBUG] failed to run npm: do you have Node.js installed and on your path? while running run_web((), {})

[ERROR] failed to run npm: do you have Node.js installed and on your path?
```

I guess that the problem must be something to do with an assumption about the path for npm. What's the assumption? What can I symlink to make this work?

Note that npm *is* found by "forge run web". This is something specific to the way that TriggerToolkit.app is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** this is fixed as of v1.4.6:
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-6

**Previous answer:**

Unfortunately I think the error message here isn't great and reflects a general problem with starting the node app.

We are aware of one issue with dependencies which started occurring after Node 0.8. Can you check what Node version you have:

```
node --version
```

If it's 0.8, then a temporary workaround to this problem is to use the command line tools and:

```
forge build
```

Then manually update development/web/package.json to refer to express 2.5.10, then

```
forge run web
```

Sorry for the trouble, we'll report back here when that's fixed

Comment: $ node --version == 
v0.8.3 ; I'll try those tweaks and report back. Thanks. I'm just a bundle of trouble, aren't I? :)

Comment: Keep us honest :) Thanks for reporting this